# Device authentication in Web API using Serial Number

Tags: authentication, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm developing a web app using ASP MVC 5 and Identity for user authentication. The users have some devices that I'm going to sell them. In the web app I can manage devices, setting device's serial number, customer (web users) and other information.

These devices have to download content related with the customer. I don't know if it is good idea to save customer's username and password in the device (app code or configuration file,...). So I thought that using device's serial number would be a good choice to authenticate the device.

So, is there any way to develop a Wep API service using the serial number or something similar to authentication process?

Comment: Can't you expose your authentication endpoints using webapi, and device will call to the server for authentication? In this case, you don't need to save anything in to the settings file.

Comment: The device have to know "who" is it to get the personalized contents from web service, so the serial number will be stored somewhere. Usually I authenticate using username and password, but now I need to use only a username (serial number). Is it posible?

Comment: I'm not sure about the exact scenario though, It's bit tricky to authenticate using serial number only, especially when serial number would publicly visible.